# Deploying website created using Polymer starter kit?

Tags: polymer

For creating my college webpage using polymer, I have downloaded polymer starter kit 1.0.2. I have customized those html files to my desired text and it runs well when I do the below.

```
gulp serve
```

opening well is chrome through

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

The problem is, it doesn't show up when I drop files into my college server. The reason for creating a website so that it can be viewed under my name like www.college.edu/~rajesh. We have public_html folder wherein if we put html/css/js files and that is it will accessible public from above URL.

when I copied the contents of app folder along with bower_component folder
the site doesn't come up whereas it work fine locally (using localhost). Only the title gets loaded however there is NO html body visible.

I am totally new to polymer. could this be done? if yes am I missing something.

Comment: Sounds like that should work. Any javascript or network errors in the console when you try to load it?

Comment: Thank you very much..I got the problem after seeing the console. I have to move the "bower_components" folder inside "app" folder. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You have to run **gulp serve:dist** which will build/vulcanize your site. Then you need to copy **app/dist** folder

Comment: I was unaware of this build step. Thanks just got to know.

Comment: I have a small query. The polymer starter kit is a single page app with routing done on browser. I am building a site with multiple pages hosted on server with same toolbar, look and feel. So what should be the correct dev workflow - work each functional page as a different build or there is a different starter for multi page.

Comment: Saying *multiple pages hosted on server with same toolbar* did you mean multiple polymer starter kit projects. If that is the case you would have to build each separately, or make a simple shell script that will do that for your or even modify the gulp script. I'm not aware of starter kit for multi page.

Answer (score 1):

Just a further clarification not sure if you ran this command, according to the readme file when you want to deploy your site you need to run

gulp

which will Build and optimize the current project, ready for deployment. This includes linting as well as vulcanization, image, script, stylesheet and HTML optimization and minification.

All the files needed will then be located in the 'dist' folder.

Build and Vulcanize [polymer starter kit github README.md](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/README.md#build--vulcanize)

Comment: I was unaware of this procedure. Thanks for letting me know.